# CSS page width 100% scroll issue in firefox 3.6

Tags: html, css

for some reason my site on Firefox 3.6 has a x scroll bar at the bottom although nothing is set to larger then 100% of the body.

This issue does not happen chrome or safari or firefox 4...

Any Ideas?

- here is the link

[www.samsaccone.com](http://www.samsaccone.com)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `overflow-x:hidden` on your body tag (or whatever the scroll bar is on)